# TLS 1.2 support IBM Cloud and app with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, tls1.2

IBM Cloud will withdraw support to TLS 1.0 and 1.1 after March 1. In the page https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/appsectls.html it says that if you try your url adding ".alt" after de subdomain and it works, then you will not have any problem. But in my case, it doesnt work, so it says that i should enable tls 1.2 but doesnt tell me how. Also, i have seen that in the "EEUU West" region there is no problem with TLS 1.2 support. Otherwise, in the "Germany" region you don't have support at first. Can you tell me how to enable TLS 1.2 in Germany region for any project? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following information was provided by an IBM Cloud platform Architect:

If your application is hosted in Germany under the eu-de.mybluemix.net domain, then TLS 1.0 is already disabled for your application, and if your clients are able to connect to it successfully then you should be ok.

The eu-de.mybluemix.net domain does not offer the alternative alt.eu-de.mybluemix.net to test with because TLS 1.0 has always been disabled for eu-de. We will be removing TLS 1.1 from the eu-de.bluemix.net domain but it is very unlikely that your clients will be using that as that is very rare.